# Adding an image over the image

Tags: html, css

I want to add an icon over the image. I am trying following, but it doesn't seem to work:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="image.jpg" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;    
}

.icon{
    background : url("icon_quick.gif") no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/tqw4V/

Comment: The reason the z-index isn't doing anything here is because child elements start their z-index position relative to the parent.  If you want the child to be *behind* the parent, you have to use a negative z-index.  Once it moves behind the parent, you'll have all sorts of nasty side effects like being unable to properly capture click events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/tqw4V/1/

Unfortunately, it requires modifying your markup, but it works. The idea is to have the overlay image be a separate element that you position absolutely over your main element. This works a lot better if the main element is not, itself, absolutely positioned.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8521029804_2c86ab5a18_m.jpg" />
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;    
}

.icon{
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: url("http://www.joors.com/se_images/icon_quick.gif") no-repeat;
    z-index: 4;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No markup modifications necessary.  Your content image (painting) stays in the markup, and the decorative image (smiley) stays part of the CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/tqw4V/6/

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    /*position: relative;  */  
}

.icon{
    /*z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;*/
    position: relative;
}

.icon:before {
    background: url("http://www.joors.com/se_images/icon_quick.gif") no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can better change your HTML, since you're adding an inner child on top of the background, which pushes it away.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="icon"></div>
            <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8521029804_2c86ab5a18_m.jpg" />
        </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;    
}

.icon{
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background : url("http://www.joors.com/se_images/icon_quick.gif") no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqw4V/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the images. Replace their positions. The smiley face should go to the html, and the other to the css. Then by height and width you can set the size of the container. Hope I've helped.